# Stuck on the existence of derivatives at specific points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am stuck in understanding how to proceed to show if the following functions admit partial derivatives at those specific points. We have been taught not to use the definition but rather to, say, evaluate $f(x, 0)$ and $f(0, y)$, that is along the axis, and then take their derivatives and evaluating them at the critical points.

Yet for these functions I’m stuck

$$f_1(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^4+y^4}{xy} & x \neq 0, y \neq 0 \\\\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$

$$f_2(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2-y^2-1}{1-x} & x^2-y^2 \neq 1, x \neq 1 \\\\ K & \text{else} \end{cases}$$

So for what concerns the first function, I am stuck because if I evaluate $f(x, 0)$ I don’t understand if this doesn’t exist, or if this is $0$ (according to the definition of $f$…?).
But if it were $0$ then the derivative would exist at any $(0, y)$ and vice versa for $(x, 0)$.

BUT on the other side, $f(x, x) = 2x^2$ whose derivative is $4x$ which is zero at any $(0, y)$

For the second function I have the same doubts: I found that $K$ should be $-2$ for the continuity, but in fact even if $K = -2$ there is no continuity.
Now, $f(1, y)$ doesn’t exist or is it $0$?

Also, say $f(x, 0) = -(x+1)$ hence the derivative does exist at $(1, 0)$?

I never faced similar exercises, I ask for some help. Thank you!

Comment: Which are "those specific points" you are talking about? At $(x,0)$, $\partial f_1/\partial x=0$ but if $x\ne0$, $f_1$ is not even continuous w.r.t. $y$.

Comment: @AnneBauval continuity is irrelevant, a function can exhibit partial derivatives at a point even if it’s not continuous at that point. I am stuck in understanding if those functions have partial derivatives at specific points, which are (0,y) (x,0) and (0,0) for the first one and (1,y) and (1,0) for the second one

Comment: Please read my comment more carefully. Continuity w.r.t. $y$ **is** relevant for the existence of a partial derivative w.r.t. $y$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Uhm, perhaps I'm expressing myself badly... What I wanted to say is that I can have a function $f(x, y)$ not continuous at $(0, 0)$ for example, but its partial derivatives at $(0, 0)$ do exist. Hence it doesn't matter if $f$ is not continuous at a point, it can still have partial derivatives at that point

Comment: Of course but that was not the point in my initial comment, so I edited an answer to show you how it **was** relefant.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f_1$ is constant on the $x$-axis, its partial derivative with respect to $x$ at *any* point of the form $(x,0)$ is $0$. On the other hand if $x\ne0$, its partial derivative  with respect to $y$ at $(x,0)$ does not exist since at such a point, $f_1$ is not even continuous with respect to $y$.

By symmetry, this answers your questions for $f_1$ at every point of the two axes (including the point $(0,0)$, where the two partial derivatives are $0$).

For the same reasons, the partial derivative of $f_2$ with respect to $y$ at *any* point of the form $(1,y)$ is $0$, and its partial derivative with respect to $x$ at $(1,y)$ *can* (perhaps) exist only if $f_2$ is continuous w.r.t. $x$ at that point, i.e. if $y=0$ and $K=-2$. Finally, if $K=-2$, $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(1,0)=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\frac{x^2-1}{1-x}+2}{x-1}$ actually exists, and equals $-1$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you please help me a bit more about this question please? What are the conditions for which a function is derivable? I understand that we say "derivable" when it's about existence of partial derivatives (a different thing wrt differentiable). Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand how to help you more. The "conditions" is the definition (which you know as well as me), and it implies continuity w.r.t. the variable w.r.t. which you are partially derivating. For instance, a necessary condition for $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(1,y_0)$ to exist is the continuity at $1$ of the map $x\mapsto f_2(x,y_0)$.